# SO Favicon not appearing in browser tabs in some versions of Firefox

Tags: bug, design, firefox, favicon

I just noticed that the favicon is missing for Stack Overflow in some versions of Firefox. It's missing whether I'm logged in or out, in a private session or normal, and regardless of whether I have any adblocker turned on.

The favicons for Meta and for other network sites are still showing, and they work fine in Chrome and Edge.

I'm on Firefox 58.0.2 and Windows 10.

I just updated to Firefox 59.0.1, and they are back, but another user has reported them missing in Firefox Dev versions as well:

> [@TylerH Yep, missing them here on FF Dev actually [...] so 60.0b4](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41699056#41699056)
>   (in Arch Linux)

Comment: Any reason to suspect this isn't a Firefox bug?

Comment: @Shog9 Well, the favicons were working in 58.0.2 and then stopped. My Firefox version and extensions didn't change, so the site must have. There have been instances before where the favicons or other styles have been broken in Firefox after changes were made.

Comment: Well, if you see it again, view source & load whatever URL is listed in the `<link rel="shortcut icon" ...` line near the top. If that's broken for some reason, then the problem's on our end.

Comment: @Shog9 Looking in the dev tools' network tab, it seems like the returned image size is 16x6840. Indeed, here is the [loaded URL](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=937412312057) compared to the [HTML `<link>` URL](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d). The link provided in the HTML works fine, but the icon that's actually loaded is bonkers. It contains all icons from all SE sites it seems.

Comment: The former image is intended to be used for stuff like the site-switcher, hot network questions sidebar, etc. It will be loaded on most pages, but it should never be referenced by the <link rel="shortcut icon" @Paul

Comment: If you're looking at the network tab in Firefox... The request isn't listed, for some reason. I verified this with a brand-new Firefox profile: first visit to SO requests http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico (which redirects to https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico), then later requests https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d (the image referenced in the <link>). But neither of these requests shows up in Firefox's dev tools This also suggests a potential source of problems if Firefox is caching the former and unable to reach the latter.

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah I tried disabling cache to no avail. Requests aren't listed, neither on SO or on MSO (but I see the favicon on MSO). I'll do some more troubleshooting to see if it's from SO or FF. Looking strongly like it's from FF for now.

Comment: Couldn't repro on Firefox 59.0.1 in Windows 7

Comment: @Sankar Yes, see the part of the question that starts "I just updated to Firefox 59.0.1, and they are back"

Comment: @TylerH My bad. I think i didn't have enough coffee at the time :p

Comment: I've been having this issue lately at random on SE sites (mostly SO chat, InfoSec, Skeptics, and LEGO) in 59.0.1 (the latest version). As yet, I've only seen it happen with SE sites, and not any other sites. Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to find steps to reproduce it consistently.

Comment: @Shog9 Did some more troubleshooting but couldn't find anything. Today, the favicon is back... Not sure what happened.

Comment: Never mind, it's gone again o_o

Comment: FWIW I have not had the issue happen for me again since updating to Firefox 59.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: It's still happening here sometimes...

Comment: I've found that uBlock Origin blocks the favicon loading for some reason. Could be relevant.